# App crashes when trying to change icon (setIcon) for next activity

Tags: java, android

Here's what I have in my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    if (MainActivity.fifty){
        menu.findItem(R.drawable.fifty).setIcon(R.drawable.fiftyf);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Now the thing is that when I delete if statement, then it works fine, but icon is not getting changed on the next activity.

Here's my xml file for menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/aud"
    android:icon="@drawable/aud"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Audience&apos;s Help"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/fifty"
    android:icon="@drawable/fifty"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="50:50"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/friend"
    android:icon="@drawable/friendhelp"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Friend&apos;s Help"/>
```

As you can see, I just started to create icon changes. The idea is that the button is 50:50 for the game called "Who wants to be a millionaire". Now in the next activity, I am trying to set R.drawable.fiftyf, which is a disabled 50:50 icon, because when user uses it, it should not be available anymore.
When I tried to add it in menu.xml, then new icon was just added, which I don't need. Please also note, that icon gets changed according to my method, but app crashes when it goes to next activity.

Thanks all.
Please let me know if additional info required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
menu.findItem(R.drawable.fifty).setIcon(R.drawable.fiftyf);
```

Should be something like this:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.fifty).setIcon(R.drawable.fiftyf);
```